# Link to HTML inside HTML doesn't work well

Tags: html, footer, html-heading

I'm working on a multipager and want to link every page to once-and-for-all-designed-header and footer. Linking seems to be working, but both header and footer consider the place given as a small area and displays a mobile version of itselves.

Here's a string I use to make a linking:

```
<object type="text/html" data="urltofile.html"></object>
```

And here's the result: HTML footer displayed improperly

[image]

So what should I do to complete this linking without this adaptiveness error?